# Use xslt to identify duplicate elements in an xml file

Tags: xslt, duplicates

I need to use xslt to identify and list all the duplicate  elements within an xml file based on label's parent being  //field @name="partya". Is there a simple way to achieve this? The xml is given below.

```
    <table>
    <entry>
     <display>
        <field name="partya">
           <label>Abi</label>
        </field>
        <field name="partyb">
           <label>Seddon</label>
        </field>
        <field name="validation-type">
           <label>auto-valid</label>
        </field>
       ...
  </entry>
  <entry>
     <display>
        <field name="partya">
           <label>Abi</label>
        </field>
```

Comment: Identifying duplicates is treated in any XSLT text book or in many questions here. Have you tried anything? Which XSLT version do you use? Are you looking for duplicated `label` elements? Or can there be other elements inside `field` elements with the `name` attribute being `partya`?

Comment: I have tried using  xslt:key but not getting very far (I'm a bit out of practice) and also researched in the questions on here. I am looking to find where the pcdata inside label is duplicated elsewhere in the file in the same context. No, this is the only structure of that type.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you could group those `label` elements and check whether there is more than one element in `current-group()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" item-separator="&#10;"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//field[@name = 'partya']/label" group-by=".">
          <xsl:if test="tail(current-group())">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvA

In XSLT 1 you can use Muenchian grouping and check whether there is more than one item in a group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="group" match="field[@name = 'partya']/label" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//field[@name = 'partya']/label[key('group', .)[2]][generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', .)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="label">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">&#10;</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvA/1

Comment: Thanks again @Martin Honnen for your response; however, I need to refine the search further. I am searching for duplicate entries within a table, but for a more accurate list of results I need to use partya and partyb values combined as there are genuine instances where partya is duplicated. Any ideas?

Comment: Ask a new question with the necessary details and your intent to solve it.